# DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple identical st.checkbox widgets with the same generated key. How to make the Key argument unique?

Tags: python, error-handling, streamlit

With Streamlit, I am trying to build a To-do list app.

This is my Error:

**DuplicateWidgetID**: There are multiple identical `st.checkbox` widgets with the same generated key.

When a widget is created, it's assigned an internal key based on its structure. Multiple widgets with an identical structure will result in the same internal key, which causes this error.

To fix this error, please pass a unique `key` argument to `st.checkbox`.

This is my code:

```
`
import streamlit as st
import functions

todos = functions.get_todos()

def add_todo():
    todo = st.session_state["new_todo"] + "\n"
    todos.append(todo)
    functions.write_todos(todos)


st.title("My Todo App")
st.subheader("This is my todo app.")
st.write("This app is to increase your productivity.")


for index, todo in enumerate(todos):
    checkbox = st.checkbox(todo, key=todo)
    if checkbox:
        todos.pop(index)
        functions.write_todos(todos)
        del st.session_state[todo]
        st.experimental_rerun()


st.text_input(label="Enter a todo", placeholder="Add new todo...",
              on_change=add_todo, key='new_todo')

print("Hello")

`
```

**I expect the code to give access the user to enter a New to-do also.**

Comment: What kind of object is todos and what are its contents? You are manually setting the key of st.checkbox to todo, so if the contents are identical, so are the keys. I suggest for debugging you simply log or print the value of todo, then you see why it's identical.